# Excel - Comparison of four columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-columns

I need to compare four columns like the ones in the image.

If **A+B** contents are identical to **C+D**, in the **E** I want to see the correct **REF** number (1st Column).

If those are not identical, I want to show **N/A** or something similar.

[image: [Image Link](http://imageshack.com/a/img921/3108/cKWoNT.png)]

What solution do you suggest?

Comment: Did the formula below work?  If so please mark as correct, by clicking on the green check mark.  If not, what did it do that it should not have?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Array formula:

```
=MATCH(C1 & D1,$A$1:$A$4 & $B$1:$B$4,0)
```

It must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter to exit edit mode.

[image: ![enter image description here]